# Windows 8 vs Windows 10 with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to create some Excel sheets and then edit them. On Windows 8 it works as expected but when it is ran on Windows 10 it does not work. It breaks at

```
xlWorkSheetEvt = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(sheetIndex);
```

I get an COM exception that says there is a Index error(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)). I am thinking in Windows 8 Worksheet.get_Item() will create a sheet without the Worksheets.Add() function but Windows 10 does not. I have the code working now for both but am very curious to know exactly what was happening. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look in to switching to Microsofts [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for reading and writing to office documents, it is much more reliable and does not require office to be installed on the machine you run it on.

Comment: Okay I will look into that thanks for the tip!

Comment: It does not like the value of your `sheetIndex` variable.  There are 2 billion of them that will raise that exception.  Start at 1 and verify that it is <= xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count

Comment: The xlWorkBookWorksheets.Count was to small originally and that is how I fixed it. I want to know why in Windows 8 I did not run into the issue of having a sheetIndex that was below the xlWorkBookWorksheets.Count